# Use bool list to retrieve elements from another list - Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have this situation:

```
main_list = [12, 10, 30, 10, 11,10, 31]
get_indices = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

What I want to do is, extract elements from `main_list` according to the boolean value in `get_indices`.
I tried the following but it is not working :

```
result = main_list[bool(get_indices)]
print result
10
```

It should be `12, 30, 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension -

```
result = [x for i, x in enumerate(main_list) if get_indices[i]]
```

You do not need to use `bool()` , `0` is considered False-like in boolean context, and anything non-zero is True-like.

Example/Demo -

```
>>> main_list = [12, 10, 30, 10, 11,10, 31]
>>> get_indices = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
>>> result = [x for i, x in enumerate(main_list) if get_indices[i]]
>>> result
[12, 30, 10]
```

---

Or if you really want something similar to your method, since you say -

> But if I was able to get my method working, I could also do for example : result = main_list[~bool(get_indices)] to get : [10, 11, 10, 31]

You can use `numpy` , convert the lists to numpy arrays. Example -

```
In [30]: import numpy as np

In [31]: main_list = [12, 10, 30, 10, 11,10, 31]

In [32]: get_indices = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

In [33]: main_array = np.array(main_list)

In [34]: get_ind_array = np.array(get_indices).astype(bool)

In [35]: main_array[get_ind_array]
Out[35]: array([12, 30, 10])

In [36]: main_array[~get_ind_array]
Out[36]: array([10, 11, 10, 31])
```

Comment: hint: if you're having difficulties reading this, imagine `()` around `(x for i,x in enumerate(main_list))`; then it's clear what's the thing that get's first generated before getting checked with `if ..`. Just imagine that, though; won't work as real code.

Comment: Correct. But if I was able to get my method working, I could also do for example : `result = main_list[~bool(get_indices)]` to get : `[10, 11, 10, 31]`

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary For that you can use `numpy` . Updated answer with example for that.

Answer (score 3):

I just came across `compress()` which is best suited for this task. 
`compress()` generates an iterator for efficient looping.

```
from itertools import compress

main_list = [12, 10, 30, 10, 11,10, 31]
get_indices = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]

print list(compress(main_list, get_indices))
[12, 30, 10]
```